# Avoid grey hover with DecoratedText in Apps Script addons

Tags: google-apps-script

Working with Apps Script addons (the new ones, based on Card UI) I use [`DecoratedText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/decorated-text) elements so I can display icons and better design my labels in the addons.

But, it always has a gray background when hovering the zone, just like a clickable element. Which they're not.

[image]

Is there a way to remove this hover effect ? (I don't declare any click action, nor any kind of action).

Can I achieve the same visual result (icon on the left or right, text wrapped or not) with [`TextParagraph`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-paragraph) instead ?

```
function getCompressFormCard(currentElement) {
  let fileText = CardService.newDecoratedText()
  .setText(currentElement.title)
.setStartIcon(CardService.newIconImage().setIconUrl(currentElement.iconUrl))
    .setWrapText(true);

  let section = CardService.newCardSection()
    .setCollapsible(false)
    .addWidget(fileText);

  return CardService.newCardBuilder().addSection(section).build();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you happen to have a sample of your decorated text code ?

Comment: yes! Just updated the post. Cheers!